# Car crash leaves man in a world devoid of animal and human life. Sees red flashes with demons and voices

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

It was a movie from the late '80's to the early '90's.

A man and his girlfriend/wife are in a car arguing, driving down a road on a stormy night. They wreck, and she is gone, and he has a bad headache. He suffers headaches throughout the movie I think.

During the day there is nobody on the planet (no animals either), but at night there are these red(?) flashes with demons and voices scaring him.

It is not the movie *The Quiet Earth*.

He lives for months (years?) going crazy until somehow he wakes up in the car with the girl in the end and only a few hours have gone by. It changes his life the end.

This one I have been looking for since I was a teen.

I saw this movie some time between 1987-1992 and was from that timeline.

It was in English. I saw this on VHS

I had a family member that owned a video rental store at the time. I think I may have seen a limited release sample that was sent to them to preview to decide if they wanted to carry it. If I remember correctly it was sent back because the royalties where too high.

Towards the end of the movie while he was alone the power went out.

He went paranoid and started raiding stores for food guns generators etc.

The things I remember the most is the empty earth and the fear of the night terrors. Also the psychological effects of long term isolation.

And the fact he never stopped looking for the girlfriend.

At the beginning I think they where arguing about their relationship, and she started to cry. I think she was driving, but I cant be sure. But that led to the car wreck due to poor visibility with heavy rain and the distraction of the argument.

Comment: I recommend you to check this website, it might help you remember the movie poster or cover of yhe vhs. You can change the genre of the movie and search in the years.  I looked for the movie but nothing. Maybe the movie is older, or from another country that was dubbed to English. https://movieweb.com/movies/1981/mystery/?page=2

Comment: A *really* long shot, but any chance that [this](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0479903/) was the man and [this](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0026361/) was the woman? I fed some of the keywords you mentioned to IMDb and it came up with something called [Cumulus 9](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123768/) from 1992, though it's doubtful this film was even officially released.